# Getting the intersection of two active record relations, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, intersect

In this rails app, I have a method called by a controller that takes an active record relation of sites and an array of filters, the method returns any sites in the relation that have all of the filters in the array. Here is the method:

```
def filter_sites(sites, filters)

  if filters.count > 0
    filterable = sites.tag_join
    filters.each { |f| sites = sites & filterable.with_tag(f) }
  end 

  return sites
end
```

Here are the scope that are used:

```
def self.tag_join
  joins(:tags).distinct
end

def self.with_tag(tag_id)
  where('sites_tags.tag_id = ?',tag_id)
end
```

This is functioning correctly but the problem is that it returns an array. My question is; is there a more effective way or writing this method and returning an active record relation? As later on in the code, further queries need to be chained.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the or method from active record

Comment: One way you could do this - but which is ugly af - is to use SQL `INTERSECT`. You basically construct an otherwise identical query for each tag and then `INTERSECT` them. This is awful because you have to do it manually, but it works and returns an ActiveRecord object which you can chain on. I also have to ask: couldn't you do `sites.where('sites_tags.tag_id = ?', filters[0]).where('sites_tags.tag_id = ?', filters[1]).where(...)`?

Comment: Isn't that just as ugly? Its a variable length array of tags so this would have to be written with a loop. I would have thought theirs a rails way of doing this, its quite common functionality...

Answer (score 2):

You could do a [merge](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge). An `array` will be returned but it is a clean call, convenient and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use sql directly with `intersect` like this:

```
filters.each do |f| 
  sql = "(#{sites.to_sql} intersect #{filterable.with_tag(f).to_sql}) as sites"
  sites = Site.from(sql)
end
```

(assuming your class name is `Site`)

I am not sure how this will go as the number of intersections piles up, but I've used it to solve a similar problem in my code when I have only 2 AR relations.